# Misconfigured external monitor on Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.3

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, hdtv, external-display

I have an external monitor (specifically, an HDTV) hooked up to my 2.53GHz 13" macbook pro.  This display works fine and I use it with my mac in clamshell mode (eg. with an external keyboard/mouse and the laptop closed and the built-in mac screen turned off)

My Mac has multiple users on it.  For User A I can use the mac with the external monitor in both clamshell and dual-monitor setups.

For User B, I can use the monitor in a dual-monitor setup, but whenever I switch to clamshell mode the Mac switches to an incorrect output resolution or frequency setting that my HDTV doesn't recognize, resulting in a blank screen and a message about Unsupported Resolution.

Chances are I did this to myself by misconfiguring my display settings at some point in the past, but I have no idea how to undo it.  I (obviously) can't seen the display to change the settings when it's borked.  I can see the display settings if I switch to Dual-monitor mode, but those settings only affect the dual monitor setup; no matter how I change the settings in dual-monitor mode, the clamshell mode setup remains borked.

How can I dig myself out of this hole?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Monitor configuration is stored in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist`. You should be able to delete that file entirely to return to default settings.

**EDIT:** Found some more. Also remove every file named `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.windowserver.`(gobbledegook)`.plist`.

Comment: Good answer.  Unfortunately, deleting that file and rebooting didn't fix the problem.  The configuration for User A works fine, but the settings for User B in clamshell mode are still wrong.

Comment: I've edited to add a few more prefs you can delete. Also be sure that System Preferences is closed when you're removing these files; it might re-create them otherwise.

Comment: FWIW, (gobbledegook) is the MAC address of en0 by default.

Comment: You did it!  The gobbledegook user pref file was the one that was screwed up.  Thanks!

Comment: It's a ByHost preference. They are used for roaming across different Macs when you have a shared network profile. Settings specific to the host you are on go in there. The code that appears there is a UUID of some kind for the machine in question. If you've migrated Macs, you can delete the ones from your old computer without any harm.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't working in 10.9.